# Attempting to share a video in iMovie '13 results in error -50

Tags: macos, sharing, imovie

I have updated to iMovie '13 (v10.01.0) and can no longer share my videos to Vimeo or export them. I get the following error message:

> Video rendering error: -50

Why is this happening and what can I do to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

That error isn't the most helpful, but you can do several things to rule out some easy problems:

1. Export onto a different drive - plug in an external with at least 10 GB of space assuming your movie isn't more than 20 minutes long.
2. Change the size and try re-exporting to your disk.
3. Open the console app and search **All Messages** for iMovie errors and post them if they are not clear to you on next steps.

Answer (score 0):

This may be because some files in the editing process may be corrupted. You could try screen recording the corrupted files and replace the files in the iMovie with the new files.